# How do I run WinRM or PsExec in all domains and not only in the same subnet?

Tags: windows, subdomain, winrm, psexec

I tested in my domain and I have this scenario:

- In a computer with IP `10.100.40.10`:

  - I can run the **WinRM** and **PsExec** on all computers with the same subnet: `10.100.40.*`
- In a computer with ip `10.200.30.50`:

  - I can also run the same in all subnets: `10.200.30.*`

But if I want to "cross" this subnet, it will fail even if I can see and check that the ports are OPEN for me. This mean:

- In ip `10.100.40.10`:

  - If I do `nmap -p 135,445,3389,5985,5986 10.200.30.-` the ports will show open!
- The same in `10.200.30.50` for the subnet `10.100.40.10`

So, how can I admin the computer on the same domain but on different subnet? What do I need to configure to make it work? What is blocking me?

Answer (score 0):

Winrm uses TCP/5985, or TCP/5986 for TLS connections need to be enabled at the firewall.

For psexec, TCP/135, and 49152-65536 need to be enabled at the firewall.

Comment: Lol.. maybe I forget the correct port. But I mean the needed ports are opens. I can access it.. This is something about the subnets...

Comment: What does a netmon packet capture show on both ends (correlated capture) when performing a winrm ping? Which winrm port are you testing? Which protocol is used for authentication?

Comment: Also the Windows firewall configuration... It's common to have local subnets granted access. There are several variations of firewall rule configuration.

Comment: humm. netmon is new for me. I will test it. About the firewall, I tried to open it. I don't know how to check it. What is the correct way to troubleshooting it? Does you have a tutorial?

Comment: It's the same host based firewall that exists on every Windows host. And there is logging for both the firewall and Winrm, which is mostly likely in a domain and using Kerberos and 5985 by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/rules